# Unable to access MySQL RDS from ec2 instance in the same private subnet

Tags: mysql, subnet, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I have my MySQL RDS instance in private subnet and have EC2 instance on the same private subnet. I have another EC2 instance in a public subnet which easily connects to RDS instance. But, my EC2 instance in private subnet unable to connect to RDS instance.

Comment: are you using the private IP to connect to it?

Comment: Yes. So from my private ec2 instance when I do

mysql -h <hostname> -P 3306 -u <usernmae> -p <password>

It says access denied for user.

Comment: make sure your `GRANT` is allowing from that host/or from everywhere and that the `<hostname>` routes.

Comment: "Access denied for user" means you can connect just fine, but you don't have permissions to do anything, including connect. There are many, many tutorials, but I asked question [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167960/help-granting-mysql-user-privileges-to-one-database-only](here) that has grants that work. You'll need to connect as root to grant.

Comment: @Tim I think I am totally confused with this GRANT thing. I am not even able to connect through root from my private instance.

Comment: You can connect to the server, you just can't authorise against the MySQL software. If it's new you will have defined the user and password when you set up RDS. You need to read about how MySQL users and permissions work. It does seem more complex than it needs to be, to me, I don't fully understand it myself.

Comment: Note that "root" is not a magic username in MySQL.  It's just the default privileged user in a stock distribution.   The privileged user is the master username chosen when setting up RDS.  To test, use *those* credentials from the instance.  That user can log in from any IP as long as the instance can be accessed at all from that IP (i.e. if the traffic is allowed by the security group).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have tried logging in with master user from private instance, but still it doesn't connect. I have already configured security groups which allows all traffic. Don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I am going through the MySQL doc

Comment: Okay, so, using the master credentials, what is the *exact* wording of the error message?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I finally solved this issue.

**What was the problem**

When i created a user, I haven't followed the correct syntax, I actually deleted the existing user and recreated it using below command.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'IP''  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

And then I have given Grant privileges for the user to the required database.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'user'@'IPt'  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

And then I tried logging in with the newly created user. That worked perfectly.

Comment: @Tim Thank You very much for the help. Your question actually helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome :) Someone needs to write a "dummies guide to MySQL users and permissions" article. I know there's a dummies book.

Comment: @Tim Haha there must be one for people.